# Edit woocommerce product post type

Tags: metabox, woocommerce-offtopic

How can I add a metabox to woocommerce product post type from an existing plugin?

The plugin author says its not currently supported, but it's a feature I need.

I've tried different things to no avail.

How can I possibly achieve that?

Below is my code:

```
if(!class_exists('KcSeoMetaData')):

    class KcSeoMetaData
    {
        function __construct()
        {
            add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', array($this, 'admin_enqueue_scripts'));
            add_action( 'save_post', array($this, 'save_KcSeo_schema_data'),10, 3);
        }

        function admin_enqueue_scripts(){
            global $pagenow, $typenow, $KcSeoWPSchema;
            // validate page
            $pt = $KcSeoWPSchema->kcSeoPostTypes();
            if( !in_array( $pagenow, array('post.php', 'post-new.php') ) )  return;
            if(!in_array($typenow, $pt)) return;

            // scripts
            wp_enqueue_script(array(
                'jquery',
                'kcseo-datepicker',
                'kcseo-select2-js',
                'kcseo-admin-js',
            ));

            // styles
            wp_enqueue_style(array(
                'kcseo-datepicker',
                'kcseo-select2-css',
                'kcseo-admin-css',
            ));

            add_action('admin_head', array($this,'admin_head'));
        }

        function admin_head(){
            global $KcSeoWPSchema;
            $pt = $KcSeoWPSchema->kcSeoPostTypes();
            foreach($pt as $postType){
                add_meta_box(
                    'kcseo-wordpres-seo-structured-data-schema-meta-box',
                    __('Structured Data Schema Settings', KCSEO_WP_SCHEMA_SLUG),
                    array($this,'meta_box_wp_schema'),
                    $postType,
                    'normal',
                    'low', 100
                );
            }
        }
        function meta_box_wp_schema($post){
            global $KcSeoWPSchema;
            wp_nonce_field( $KcSeoWPSchema->nonceText(), '_kcseo_nonce' );
            $schemas = new KcSeoSchemaModel;
            $html = null;
            $html .="<div class='schema-tips'>";
            $html .= "<p><span>Tip:</span> Once you save these structured data schema settings, validate this page url here:<a href='https://developers.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool/' target='_blank' >Google's structured data testing tool</a></p>";

            $html .="</div>";
            $html .= "<div class='schema-holder'>";
            $html .= '<div id="meta-tab-holder" class="rt-tab-container">';
            $htmlMenu = null;
            $htmlCont = null;
            $htmlMenu .= "<ul class='rt-tab-nav'>";
            $schemaFields = $schemas->schemaTypes();
            foreach($schemaFields as $schemaID => $schema){
                $tabId = $KcSeoWPSchema->KcSeoPrefix.$schemaID;
                $htmlMenu .= '<li><a href="#'.$tabId.'">'.$schema['title'].'</a></li>';
                $htmlCont .="<div id='{$tabId}' class='rt-tab-content'>";
                $metaData = get_post_meta($post->ID, $tabId, true );
                $metaData = (is_array($metaData) ? $metaData : array());
                foreach($schema['fields'] as $fieldId => $data){
                    $data['fieldId'] = $fieldId;
                    $data['id'] = $tabId."_".$fieldId;
                    $data['name']=$tabId."[{$fieldId}]";
                    $data['value'] = (!empty($metaData[$fieldId]) ? $metaData[$fieldId] : null);
                    $htmlCont .= $schemas->get_field($data);
                }
                $htmlCont .="</div>";
            }
            $htmlMenu .="</ul>";
            $html .= $htmlMenu .$htmlCont;
            $html .= "</div>";
            $html .= "</div>";
            echo $html;
        }

        function save_KcSeo_schema_data($post_id,$post, $update){
            if (defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE) return $post_id;
            global $KcSeoWPSchema;
            $nonce  = !empty($_REQUEST['_kcseo_nonce']) ? $_REQUEST['_kcseo_nonce'] : null;
            if (!wp_verify_nonce($nonce , $KcSeoWPSchema->nonceText())) return $post_id;

            // Check permissions
            if (!empty($_GET['post_type'])) {
                if (!current_user_can('edit_' . $_GET['post_type'], $post_id)) return $post_id;
            }
            $pt = $KcSeoWPSchema->kcSeoPostTypes();
            if (!in_array($post->post_type,$pt) ) return $post_id;

            $meta = array();
            $schemaModel = new KcSeoSchemaModel;
            $schemaFields = $schemaModel->schemaTypes();
            foreach($schemaFields as $schemaID => $schema){
                $schemaMetaId = $KcSeoWPSchema->KcSeoPrefix.$schemaID;
                $data = array();
                foreach($schema['fields'] as $fieldId => $fieldData){
                    $value = (!empty($_REQUEST[$schemaMetaId][$fieldId]) ? $_REQUEST[$schemaMetaId][$fieldId] : null);
                    $value = $KcSeoWPSchema->sanitize($fieldData, $value);
                    $data[$fieldId] = $value;
                }
                $meta[$schemaMetaId] = $data;
            }
            if(count($meta) > 0){
                foreach($meta as $mKey => $mValue){
                    update_post_meta($post_id, $mKey, $mValue);
                }
            }
        }

    }

endif;
```

Comment: This question is off-topic because it's related to a third party plugin, but it looks like the code is bailing because the post type `product` is not part of the array returned by `$pt = $KcSeoWPSchema->kcSeoPostTypes();`

Comment: Yeah I tried to add if (!in_array($product->post_type,$pt) ) return $post_id;